# Where is IIS Manager for Remote Administration for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, iis, remote

1. There are several reference of
   `IIS Manager for Remote Administration` for Windows 10 (I'm using enterprise version) on [iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/t/1232518.aspx) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/blc4zu/iis_manager_on_windows_10_1809_no_option_to/), they point to a Microsoft page, however the [link to Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177) is now dead.

   The package is also present in [Web Platform Components](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), but the installation fails with the same error.

   Furthermore that's for version previous to v10 (my target).
2. I could not see any package in "Turn Windows features on/off".
3. Yet, there are few RSAT packages (features on demand):

   `Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online |select-object -property displayname, state` to list what is available and
   `Get-Windowscapability -online -name Rsat.RemoteAccess.Management.Tools* | Add-WindowsCapability -online` to install `Rsat.RemoteAccess.Management.Tools`

   But unfortunately this does not allow remote administration of IIS on servers from Windows 10.

How can I do remote management of IIS v10 from Windows 10 enterprise from now on ?

Comment: The download is dead at this moment like you found. Before Microsoft fixes that, you have to resort to other alternatives (like RDP directly to the IIS server).

Comment: @LexLi "This is a Microsoft Supported Download   |   Works With: IIS 7, IIS 7.5, IIS 8, IIS 8.5" which is not v10 anyway.

Comment: Here's a link i found to someones google drive, remember to verify the digital signature (right click + properties) before opening https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dHIDVfUT75J6vUfHe9aG4q4K3uI8lfiP/view?usp=sharing